# Flex: how to manage cookies in mx:HTML?

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript-3, cookies, air

I use AIR HTML component, and I need to delete cookies sometimes. I have to open IE and delete cookies there... Can I do it via AS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#manageCookies

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#useCache

Essentially you can tell AIR NOT to save cookies and or consult the local cache on a per-use (application level) basis.